# jQuery Custom app integration with Wordpress

Tags: jquery, mysql, wordpress, integration

I created html/jquery app, which I am currently running by embedding it within one of the pages as a raw html.

Website has Wishlist member plugin running.

I need to integrate app with WordPress in such a way, so I will be able to save/retrieve some JSON data in a database, under current user, so only that user can have an access to it.

I am still very fresh in programming, and any help/direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's for code-specific, not broad, questions. Please post the relevant code and show your effort, and we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the "warm welcoming" -1 nice gesture for nubie! It is warm feeling starting here in negative space.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then ask again. We are more than willing to help you, we are not willing to do it for you. It's best to show your effort, what have you tried? What research have you done? Are you hung up somewhere? Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote on why this question was downvoted

Comment: @Srdjan - don't take it personally. Questions are judged on their merits, not on whether someone's new. I gave you the advice that was necessary in order for you to GET HELP. Remember, we are all here to help people for free, we don't get paid. We are your friends in this regard - but we need the right info in your question.

Comment: This is getting better and better, just keep 'em coming, only 3 negative comments, you guys can do better than that :)

Comment: Anyway, Don't know if all of you on this forum knew much of a muchness, and you were ALL born with great knowledge. Well I am one of few who don't know where to turn for the help. I thought that this is the place where there are no stupid questions (well, if you don't know the coding you are proclaimed as outcast) and I am thinking where humanity went. If I was physically there, you would of shoot me without blinking. Anyway in the meantime, I was busy with course for making plugins for Wordpress, where I discovered, nothing is making sense, and nothing is bringing me closer to solution,

Comment: Before this I took a course in jquery, ajax, mysql and PHP. Unfortunately I don't know much about PHP, and I in fact need just a few lines, or something in that sense, so no need to spend next 6 months studying PHP. That was the reason, that I came here in the first place, to ask for direction, as I don't know where to start, and not that I did not try. I spent 4 days Googling and studying and no luck. I was very polite, and took me a great deal of time to ask this question.

Comment: After all, when you all give me as much downgrades, for asking for direction, just for one minute think: where all humanity is gone? Do you feel better? I certainly don't. Have a great day ahead, and lots of success...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually find an answer by myself, and it wasn't so difficult after all...
Create custom template page, that needs to be a PHP file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Your Custom Name
 *
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />

    <!-- page title, displayed in your browser bar -->
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_home() ? bloginfo('description') : wp_title(''); ?></title>

    <!-- add feeds, pingback and stuff-->
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body id="top">
<div class='container_wrap' id='main'>
    <div class='container'>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

<!--        Your HTML content here-->

</body>
</html>
```

"Your Custom Name" will be shown inside wordpress page , on the right hand side, so you can choose as your custom template.

You can insert your code inside "Your HTML content here".

I find that template here https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/blank-wordpress-template-no-header-no-footer-no-sidebar?utm_expid=3606929-109.P6e7JvhjTrWFxwrJZjRkog.0

Now, the best place to insert this file will be inside child theme folder, safest way. If you need instructions about child theme, there is a good article http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-a-wordpress-child-theme/

That worked for me. Good luck!